# index match two columns error

Tags: vba, indexing, match

I'm trying to implement an index+match formula by using two columns as references to get a third column.

I have the following table and the code.
Any suggestions?

```
billy   FESTO   1
billy   FELIPE  2
billy   JOHNY   3
billy   MARCO   4
billy   TOS     5
john    CASTRO  6
```

---

```
Sub test()
    Dim teste As String

    teste = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("C1:C100"), WorksheetFunction.Match("billy" & "&" & "TOS", Range("A1:A100") & "&" & Range("B1:B100"), 0),1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't do an array formula with WorksheetFunctions.

Comment: Loop through the rows and test whether the two columns equal the values and return the first that is true.  Use worksheetFunctions sparingly in vba.

Comment: Don't iterate the cells of a `Range`. Dump the `Range` into a 2D variant array, and iterate the array instead, using a `For` loop. Otherwise your next question will be "how can I make this code run faster?"